# Spark + Scala: Provide dynamic list of aggregations

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I´m using a number of `User-defined Aggregations` that I apply on a DataFrame after doing a `groupBy`. I would like to have both the columns for the `groupBy` and the aggregations defined dynamically.

As an example, I am able to do it for the grouping columns:

```
// These are my grouping columns 
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val columns = f.dimensions.map(column => col(column))

// This is my UDAF
val myAgg = new ComponentSumAggregation[String, Float](StringType, FloatType, _ + _,"kpi_1")

// Here I dynamically apply the grouping but the aggregation is "hardcoded"
val kpi2DF = df.groupBy(columns : _*).agg(myAgg($"facts").as("kpi_2"),myAgg($"facts").as("kpi_3"),myAgg($"facts").as("kpi_4"))
```

Now, what I would like to do is to have a collection of `UDAFs` that I defined somewhere else and pass it to the `agg` method (instead of hardcoding it), but I can not get it to work.

**Try #1**: If I use the overloaded version of `agg` that requires the column name before the aggregation varargs, I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: expression 
'genericfact.`facts`' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an 
aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if 
you don't care which value you get.;;
```

While trying to do this:

```
// Perform the aggregation
val kpi2DF = df.groupBy(columns : _*).agg($"facts",myAggs : _*)
```

If I try to add 'facts' to the grouping columns, it complains about it being of Map type.

**Try #2** If I just go for the var args approach, trying to refactor what already works... I does not even compile:

```
val myAggs = List(myAgg($"facts").as("kpi_2"),myAgg($"facts").as("kpi_3"),myAgg($"facts").as("kpi_4"))

// Perform the aggregation
val kpi2DF = df.groupBy(columns : _*).agg(myAggs : _*)
```

It says, it requires a `Seq[String]` and not a `Seq[Column]`

Any idea on how could I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: The implementation of ´ComponentSumAggregation´ is not relevant here as invoking it multiple times in the 'agg' works. The question is not on how to perform UDAF but to invoke them dynamically. Did you read the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Head and tail:

```
 df.groupBy(columns : _*).agg(myAggs.head, myAggs.tail : _*)
```

Comment: can you explain your answer with a little more details, then just one line of code?

Comment: Well, it is totally bizarre but it works all right. Moreover, if you take a look to the inner implementation, both head and tail are appended together before creating a new DataFrame...

Comment: The (relevant) signature for agg is: def agg(expr : Column, exprs : Column*). Notice that it needs at least one parameter. The head/tails expression forces the call to conform to the signature by providing one column as first parameter, and the tail as varargs.